# Automatically create multiple python datasets based on column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a huge data set with columns like: "`Eas_1`", "`Eas_2`", and so on to "`Eas_40`" and "`Nor_1`" to "`Nor_40`". I want to automatically create multiple separate data sets that consist of all columns that end with the same number (grouped by column name number) and column number pasted as values in the new column (`Bin`).

My data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Eas_1": [3, 4, 9, 1],
"Eas_2": [4, 5, 10, 2],
"Nor_1": [9, 7, 9, 2],
"Nor_2": [10, 8, 10, 3],  
"Error_1": [2, 5, 1, 6], 
"Error_2": [5, 0, 3, 2], 
})
```

I don't know how to create `Bin` column and paste the column name values, but I could separate data sets manually like this:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='_1')
df2 = df.filter(regex='_2')
```

This would take a lot of effort for me, plus I  would have to change the script every time I get new data. This is how I imagine end result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"Eas_1": [3, 4, 9, 1],
"Nor_1": [9, 7, 9, 2],
"Error_1": [2, 5, 1, 6], 
"Bin": [1, 1, 1, 1], 
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the suffixes with `.str.extract`, then groupby on those:

```
suffixes = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False)

for label, data in df.groupby(suffixes, axis=1): 
    print('-'*10, label, '-'*10)
    print(data)
```

**Note** To collect your dataframes, you can do:

```
dfs = [data for _, data in df.groupby(suffixes, axis=1)]

# access the second dataframe
dfs[1]
```

Output:

```
---------- 1 ----------
   Eas_1  Nor_1  Error_1
0      3      9        2
1      4      7        5
2      9      9        1
3      1      2        6
---------- 2 ----------
   Eas_2  Nor_2  Error_2
0      4     10        5
1      5      8        0
2     10     10        3
3      2      3        2
```

Comment: Looks promising! Is there a way that I can get it as a separate data frame? For example a df2 (which only consists of Eas_2, Nor_2, Error_2)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see updated answer.

Comment: That solves the hardest part of my question... Grate!  If I don't get any better responses, I will mark yours as an answer.